# Can I get my Windows tablet to be a Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I have a Lenovo tablet running Windows 10 for Windows app development, however deployment is easier with a Windows Phone. Is there any way that I can get my tablet to be, or pretend to be, a Windows Phone?

Comment: Turns out deployment is ok if you install VS Remote Tools for remote debugging, but question still stands for curiosity's sake

Comment: Have you used Simulator in it???  What version VS you are using???

Comment: @NiravMadariya Yes I have used the simulator; I'm on VS2015. I still want to use a physical Windows Phone device.